# Windows Server 2019 Task Scheduler - Task running but not appearing anywhere

Tags: windows, windows-task-scheduler, tasks

I imported a Task on Windows Server 2019 and I got some errors. The Task Scheduler was completely stuck so I deleted the task from `c:\Windows\System32\Tasks` and from the registry. I then re-imported the Task after fixing the xml file.

Now the Task is running (without issue) everyday, but I need the stop it.

I can see the Task on the Scheduler under "Task Status" (which basically just shows the Task run in the last 24h), but this is the **only place** where I can see it.

I can't see it on the Scheduler's Active Task or in the Task Library, nor in `c:\Windows\System32\Tasks`. Even `schtasks` doesn't show the task. Also the registry doesn't show it.

Edit: also can't see it in the Administrator Powershell `Get-ScheduledTask`.

Where is then the Task? How can I delete it?

Comment: Can you see it if you run this in an Administrator Powershell? `Get-ScheduledTask`

Comment: No, it's not there...

Comment: Is there anything in `c:\Windows\System32\Tasks`? Does Autoruns show anything?

Comment: Nothing there... the Task seems completely disappeared

Comment: Can you see anything being logged to EventViewer?

Comment: yes Task is logged by the EventViewer..

Comment: Please provide the full EventViewer entry

Answer (score 0):

I had to reboot the machine in order to make the task disappear.